# I would like to build language analyzer from scratch for new language which is not supported in Elasticsearch. What steps should I take?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to build Amharic language syntax analyzer so that I can index Amharic texts and search based on Amharic. But there is no built in support for Amharic language analyzer in Elasticsearch.

I am just trying to see if it is possible by using very few words.
What steps should I take? The examples should not be definitely for Amharic but If I know how for other languages, I can use for Amharic too.